# How to sync all Gmail with iPod touch?

Tags: ipod-touch, data-synchronization, ios, email, gmail

I entered my Gmail info in the Mail app on my iPod touch, and I can now read my email on my iPod.  That's great as far as it goes, but I want to sync *all* of my email to my iPod.

Right now, it only seems to load a couple hundred messages, plus any that I specifically choose to read - which I suppose is good for minimizing bandwidth usage, but the whole point of syncing email to my iPod is so I can read messages when I have no network at all.

Is there a button or setting to sync all email that I just haven't found yet?  Or one of those cryptic unlabeled icons?

Answer (score 2):

If you add your Google account as an Exchange account you can theoretically sync an unlimited amount of Email on your device. To do this, follow the instructions at Google to use Google Sync with Gmail (http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=138740) and after that change the option "Mail Days to Sync" to "No Limit". The Option "Show XX Recent Messages" will be ignored (this is actually intended behavior, see http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2723).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the iOS has an option to keep all email from an account. I believe the maximum is 200 messages.